# how to configure prettier to make code in one line

Tags: prettier

I have write some code in vue file.It has many lines.I want to set them to one line.I use prettirec to format my code.
this is my vue code

```
Math.floor(
              (Math.max.apply(
                null,
                this.client.trailCourse.records.map((d) => d.sessionIndex)
              ) -
                1) /
                4
            ) + 1;
```

I want to I become like this

```
Math.floor((Math.max.apply(null, this.client.trailCourse.records.map((d) => d.sessionIndex)) -1) /4) + 1;
```

How can I set my prettierrc?thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1):

Change the properties below

```
"printWidth": 120,
```

Comment: this does not work for me.I have set this to 300.I set it to 10000.It also does not work for me.It may cause by other reason.

Answer (score 0):

It is not recommended to do it as prettier uses the best practices to style the code and it is more recommended to make shorter lines for better readability.

If you still want to do it you can override the default settings.
You can change the `printWidth` property to a wider length in the `.prettierrc` file.

Comment: Yeal,I think you are right.But chaning printWidth does not work for me.And in my code,it changes line at multiple place.It cause worse readability.

Comment: @Smile It might happen that because of parentheses it breaks lines. In that case, you cannot make it prettier to do one line. You can set prettier to ignore this specific use case by using "// prettier-ignore" or refactor this code.